# how to get a specific shape div using Css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

hi I want to get this tilted background div

[image]

any idea how is it possible as I am new to web development

Comment: Why `<div>`? Why not [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG)

Comment: i didnt know that its possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would require `clip-path:polygon()` CSS property for this with the co-ordinates as per your requirement.

Try something like this:

```css
.polygon {
  height: 90px;
  width:300px;
  background:red;
  clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 98% 100%, 95% 50%, 30% 80%);
}
```

```html
<div class="polygon">
</div>
```

**Note:** Adjust as per your requirement